# 50% higher bit rate vs 20% higher resolution

Tags: video-quality, bitrate

I have two videos: first one has 50% higher bit rate, second one has 20% higher resolution and slightly higher FPS. Which one will look better? I use a 1080p 72 inch 60 Hz screen at 10 feet distance.

```
Video 1

Format : AVC
Format/Info : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile : High@L4
Format settings, CABAC : Yes
Format settings, RefFrames : 13 frames
Codec ID : V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
Duration : 1 h 18 min
Bit rate : 2 966 kb/s
Width : 1 056 pixels
Height : 594 pixels
Display aspect ratio : 16:9
Frame rate mode : Constant
Frame rate : 23.976 FPS
Color space : YUV
Chroma subsampling : 4:2:0
Bit depth : 8 bits
Scan type : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame) : 0.197
Stream size : 1.63 GiB (71%)
Language : English
Default : Yes
Forced : Yes
Color range : Limited
Color primaries : BT.709
Transfer characteristics : BT.709
Matrix coefficients : BT.709

Video 2

Format : AVC
Format/Info : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile : High@L4.1
Format settings, CABAC : Yes
Format settings, RefFrames : 5 frames
Codec ID : V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
Duration : 1 h 15 min
Bit rate : 2 073 kb/s
Width : 1 280 pixels
Height : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio : 16:9
Frame rate mode : Constant
Frame rate : 25.000 FPS
Color space : YUV
Chroma subsampling : 4:2:0
Bit depth : 8 bits
Scan type : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame) : 0.090
Stream size : 1.09 GiB (78%)
Language : English
Default : Yes
Forced : No
Color range : Limited
Matrix coefficients : BT.709
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you give files (or png screenshots) to comparing?
I think that file with higher bitrate and higher resolution should look better, with other conditions being equal.

1056*594 = 627 264 pixels.
1280*720 = 921 600 pixels (47% more pixels relative to 1056x594 resolution)
921 600 / 627 264 = 1.469 * 100% = 147% relative to 1056x594 resolution.

2966 kbps for 1056x594 - 43% more bitrate for this video, relative to 1280x720
2073 kbps for 1280x720
2966 / 2073 = 1.43 * 100% = 143% relative to bitrate of 1280x720 video.

What do you think?
I think that with these settings both videos should be approx equals. Maybe the subjectivity of the perception of the human view will make its adjustments in this comparing.

Comment: The files are too large to send them

Comment: You can upload png screenshots to comparsion image hosting or to cloud drive and attach link to the next comment.

Comment: It is supposed to be the same frame from the 2 videos, right? There is no point comparing different frames? How I am to find exactly the same frame in two videos?

Comment: You can find the same frame in any video editing software. Or with ffmpeg, as example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27568254/how-to-extract-1-screenshot-for-a-video-with-ffmpeg-at-a-given-time